# Happens-before mechanism in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, java-memory-model

I've got the question about happens-before mechanism in Java. Here is the example:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

        int a = 0;
        volatile int b = 0;

        public void run() {


            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            read();
        }

        public void write(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;  
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void read() {
            System.out.println(a + " " + b);
        }


    }
```

This is clear example of happens-before and this is safe enough, as I know. `a` will get new value properly, because it stands before `b`'s initialization. But does reordering mean that safety is not guaranteed? I'm talking about this:

```
public void write(int a, int b) {
    this.b = b;
    this.a = a;//might not work? isn't it?
}
```

**UPD** Main thread:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
        t.write(1, 2);


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that includes the start() call? I'm not able to understand exactly what you are asking here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making `b` `volatile` and having `write` set a value to `b` after it sets a value to `a` guarantees that:

1. if `b` is read before `a`, then
2. `a`'s value will not be older than the value it had when `b` was previously written to.

Namely, the write to `b` and the read from `b` act as a synchronization point, or a fence, which means whatever was written to `a` before the write to `b` will be readable after the read from `b` (if `a` is written to more than once, the following writes might or might not be visible).

However, your code is not safe as it is now. In `read`, you have the following expression:

```
a + " " + b
```

In Java, [expressions are evaluated left-to-right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1). Which means, `a` will be evaluated before `b`. Consequently, it is completely possible that the read of `a` will see an old value of `a`, while the read of `b` will see a new value of `b`. Had you had `b` read before `a`, the happen-before relation between `b`'s write and read would have covered the write to `a` and the read from `a`. Now, it doesn't.

As for reordering operations in `write` - that will clearly eliminate the effect `b`'s ordering guarantees have over operations on `a`, even if `read` first reads `b` and then reads `a`.

To visualize things, given only `b` is `volatile`:

The current code does not guarantee ordering of operations on a -

```
write a                         read a
write b --> happens before -->  read b
```

Reordering `write` using the given read will not order `a` as well -

```
                                read a
write b --> happens before -->  read b
write a
```

And even if the given `read` is fixed, `a` will not be ordered by `b` -

```
write b --> happens before -->  read b
write a                         read a
```

The only safe thing to do is keeping the current `write`, and fixing the `read` -

```
write a
write b --> happens before -->  read b
                                read a
```